# Find then save web page to Drive Using C#

Tags: c#

i have a problem i want to find a specific string in a web page then save the web page that i found the string.

I am using firefox for web browser

Problem :
1. I open a page (Containing a random word)
2. Then my C# program doing searching in the page, if the word find in the page then program will automaticaly save the page to Drive . If not the program will do click on Next Button on the page then do search again in the page.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: not yet, i still find how to find string in web page using C#

Comment: In what format do you need to save the page?

Comment: You'll need to write the program yourself - no one is going to deliver you full code based on vague requirements.  To point you in the right direction, a GET request will typically pull in a web page if you have a URL, `File.WriteAllText` and `File.WriteAllBytes` will save text or binary to the hard drive, and a search engine such as Google will find URLs based on search text.  Research those and do your best - you can always post specific questions here.

Comment: @Peter .html format

Comment: I think your intention to manipulate firefox using some sort of c# program is not the best idea for this case. c# has `HttpClient` that's fully capable of reading HTML. No need to use firefox or any browser for it. But @ElementalPete is correct. You should at least give it a try before posting.

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question), [ask], and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it sounds like you might want to do something like the following.

You can use WebClient to load the response from a url into a string:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    string s = client.DownloadString(your_url);
}
```

You can then search for a occurrence of the string you a looking for in "s" using indexOf:

```
if (s.IndexOf("string you are searching for") > -1)
{
    // s contains "string you are searching for"
}
```

Then you can save "s" to disk using a StreamWriter:

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file name"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(s);
}
```

In terms of clicking the "next" button can you define the urls as a list of strings and then just iterate over them using the previous code for each.